# Transition/animation not working if element is before the toggle

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to animate the visibility of a few elements, and I isolated this code to show that only the elements after the toggle work, not the ones before (the thing I would need): is there any explanation for this behaviour???
I'm using Chrome latest version for the tests.

```css
.element-1 {
    transform-origin: top;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.element-1 {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
</div>

<div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle">Toggle Element</label>

<div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
</div>

<div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's your CSS primter: `~` means _any matching element following the selector defined before the ~_. So it does exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: `~` selector selects only subsequent not previous

Comment: Thank you, guys. Now I understand, and I'm studying this kind of selectors, that I didn't know. I don't know now who to give credit for the right answer (you are both correct!).

Comment: It's fine if you want to mark @MadanBhandari 's answer, he did the effort of typing it up for you. Good luck with learning CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` selector selects only subsequent not previous that's why it doesn't work for previous siblings. You can [read more about this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

However here is workaround to select previous siblings as well, you need to add wrapper and use `:has` to select all siblings.

```css
.element-1 {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper:has(input:checked) .element-1 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <label for="toggle">Toggle Element</label>

  <div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="element-1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Nulla faucibus nisi nec ullamcorper finibus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note: `:has` is currently not _yet_ widely supported. Can't wait for it to be widely supported, but for now, it's not yet a viable option for production.